# Как остановить скрипт работающий в фоне

Tags: linux, putty

Запустил скрипт командой

> nohup php /folder/script.php &

там цикл и он будет работать бесконечно. как остановить конкретно этот скрипт не перезагружая сервер?

Comment: `ps aux | grep php` → выбрать pid скрипта → `kill <PID>`; если всё ещё продолжет дрыгаться, то `kill -9 <PID>`.

Comment: чтобы потом не грепить: `nohup php /folder/script.php & pid=$!`, как надоест, `echo $pid` или `kill $pid` - если консоль не закрывали